# How to update set number of records with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
ID | user_id| game_id
```

I need to tell mysql to update game_id=? where user_id=? and game_id=0 for a set amount of records (100, 250, etc). Is there a easy way to do this in mysql, or do I have to do it in PHP?

Comment: update has a `LIMIT` clause. I would never do it without an `ORDER BY`

Comment: You mean you want to update game_id where user_id is 100, 250.. ??

Comment: Did you try using WHERE IN?

Comment: Sorry, im beyond tired. Let me clarify. I want to update game_id to equal $var1 where user_id=$var2 AND game_id=0. But i need to do it to a $var3 number of records (100 or 250, etc).

Comment: `$sql="update table set game_id='$var1' where user_id='$var2' order by game_id limit $var3";` ?? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Ok, i think that will work if I add a where user_id='$var2' and game_id=0

Not sure why I would need the order by clause though. Will that update more than 1 record?

Comment: yes @Marc Hoover it will update

Comment: so, say you have 300 rows that match the criteria. How do you decide which 250 of those to update?

Comment: @Strawberry, WHERE user_id=$var AND game_id=0

I think im just overtired and overthinking this.

Comment: That's underthinking - but yes often associated with tiredness.

Comment: @Strawberry I was actually overthinking it because I was trying to make it more complicated than it was. I got some rest and I'm all better now, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, i was just overtired and overthinking this. @Drew had it right. Just use a LIMIT clause.

```
UPDATE uc_tickets SET game_id=? WHERE user_id=? AND game_id=0 LIMIT ?
```

Comment: To a rough approximation, a LIMIT clause ALWAYS requires an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Call this from whatever language you want. It is a stored proc. Remember, if you don't use an `ORDER BY`, it is going to be haphazzard. We are risk-adverse afterall.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    game_id INT NOT NULL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT myTable(game_id,user_id) VALUES (1,1),(1,1),(2,2),(33,1);
```

Stored Proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uspUpdateChunk;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE uspUpdateChunk
(   p_game_id INT,
    p_user_id INT,
    p_limit INT
)
BEGIN
    SET @sql=CONCAT('UPDATE myTable SET game_id=',p_game_id,' WHERE user_id=',p_user_id,' ');
    SET @sql=CONCAT(@sql,'ORDER BY game_id LIMIT ',p_limit);
    -- select @sql; -- rem out for debugging purposes
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
call uspUpdateChunk(777,1,2);
+----+---------+---------+
| id | game_id | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |     777 |       1 |
|  2 |     777 |       1 |
|  3 |       2 |       2 |
|  4 |      33 |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

yep, updated just 2 of the `user_id`=1

so `ORDER BY` something. `id`, whatever.

MySQL Manual page entitled [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Always seems to use [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). And it is **crucial** that the `@sql` is a User Variable (with an `@` sign), and not a Local Variable from a `DECLARE`. Not that the manual seems to tell anyone that. Can waste hours if you don't do that right.

Comment: Thats awesome, but a limit clause and some sleep is actually all i need.